# Help me approximate this sum: $S = \sum_{j=2}^{N}{\frac{\ln \ln \ln \ j}{( \ln \ln \ j)^2}}$

Tags: integration, summation, asymptotics, approximation, approximate-integration

I would like to figure out the asymptotic rate of growth for the sum $S = \sum_{j=2}^{N}{\frac{\ln \ln \ln j}{( \ln \ln j)^2}}$  in the limit of large $N$.

Ultimately, I want to know if $S(N)$ is $O(N^{2})$, $O(N \ln \ln \ln \ln \ln \ln \ln N)$, etc.

This problem occurred in calculating the expected entropy of a particular system. Really, I'm just trying to calculate the asymptotic form of the Shannon Entropy for a particular function.

I really don't know a lot of techniques for such a weird problem. I feel like there are two ways forward: Bound the sum with an integral and try to evaluate that: $S \approx \int_{j=2}^{N}{\frac{\ln \ln \ln j \ dj}{(\ln \ln j)^2}}$.

Or we can use some tricky properties of logs:

\begin{align}
e^S &= \exp\left[\sum_{j}^{N}{\ln \ln \ln j} - \sum_{j}^{N}{(\ln \ln j)^2}\right] \\
&= \exp\left[\ln (\prod_{j}^{N}{\ln \ln j)} - \sum_{j}^{N}{(\ln \ln j)^2}\right] \\
&= (\prod_{j}^{N}{\ln \ln j})\ e^{- \sum_{j}^{N}{(\ln \ln j)^2}}
\end{align}

Therefore $ S = \ln (\prod_{j}^{N}{\ln \ln j}) -  \sum_{j}^{N}{(\ln \ln j)^2}$.

Comment: How do you transofm division to subtract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that the function changes so slowly that the sum would be 
$$O(N\ln\ln\ln N/(\ln\ln N)^2)$$
For example, when $N=10^{80}$, the value of $\ln\ln\ln N/(\ln\ln N)^2=0.0607$, while for $N=10^{100}$, the value is $0.0572$.  So when you sum up to $10^{100}$, the value is within $6\%$ of the end value for $99.999999999999999999\%$ of the time.